# Dynamically adding a class to a link while changing width of the item

Tags: jquery

I currently have a link within a li, the below Jquery works when i click the link to make the width of the `<li>` larger and then close it when its larger back to its original state.

My question is how can i amend the below Jquery to add other class to the `<a>` when its open and remove it when its closed

`<li>` at 145px wide: `<a href="" class="followtextheader open">Follow us</a>`

`<li>` at 50px: `<a href="" class="followtextheader">Follow us</a>`

```
<li class="followUs special">
  <a href="" class="followtextheader">Follow us</a>
</li>


$(document).ready( function(){
    $('.followtextheader').click( function() {
        event.preventDefault()
        var toggleWidth = $(".followUs").width() == 50 ? "145px" : "50px";
        $('.followUs').animate({ width: toggleWidth });
    });
});
```

thanks in advance

Comment: `$('.followtextheader').click( function(event) {   event.preventDefault();`

Comment: Where is the rest of your code @KrishR? It doesn't answer the OP's question about toggling a class.

Comment: @Jay Blanchard, OP missed to add `event` from click handler.i.e he got an error like `ReferenceError: event is not defined`

Comment: Yes he did @KrishR, but you should have told him that in your comment as the comment did not solve the question.

Comment: i got that i missed a ;, thank you i did wonder where the rest of the answer was :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add this line to the function -

```
$(this).toggleClass('open');

$('.followtextheader').click( function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).toggleClass('open');
        var toggleWidth = $(".followUs").width() == 50 ? "145px" : "50px";
        $('.followUs').animate({ width: toggleWidth });
    });
```